# How to clean canvas and re-draw again

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So I made a simple example that if u click on a canvas, it keep drawing random lines,
and it also pushes the current state into `_history` variable, and once you clicked on a "get previous" button, it pop up the previous state.

```js
var _history = []
var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('canvas')[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   
canvas.addEventListener('click', generateLine, false);

var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0];

btn.addEventListener('click', loadPrevious, false);

var img = document.getElementsByClassName('img')[0];


function generateLine() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(Math.random() * 200, Math.random() * 200);
    ctx.stroke();
 
 var value = canvas.toDataURL();
 console.log(value);
 _history.push(value);
}

function loadPrevious() {
 _history.pop();
 var value = _history.pop();
 
 img.src = value;
 
 // clear data
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 
 // re-draw
 ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
```

```css
.canvas {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

.app {
 text-align: center;
}

img {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
 <img alt="test" class="img" />
 Click on the image to draw random: <br />
 <canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
 <br />
 <button class="btn">load previous state</button>
</div>
```

The `_history` array is good, and when I pop a state it returns a good URI image, but I think the part of "loading" the state to the canvas is broken.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the image in memory is asynchronous so you need to wrap it in a `img.onload` function.

```js
var _history = []
var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('canvas')[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.addEventListener('click', generateLine, false);

var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0];

btn.addEventListener('click', loadPrevious, false);

var img = document.getElementsByClassName('img')[0];


function generateLine() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(Math.random() * 200, Math.random() * 200);
    ctx.stroke();

    var value = canvas.toDataURL();
    console.log(value);
    _history.push(value);
}

function loadPrevious() {
    _history.pop();
    var value = _history.pop();

    img.src = value;

    // clear data
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // re-draw
    img.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    };
    
}
```

```html
<style>
.canvas {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.app {
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    display: none;
}
</style>

<div class="App">
    <img alt="test" class="img" />
    Click on the image to draw random: <br />
    <canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
    <br />
    <button class="btn">load previous state</button>
</div>
```